# how do i make sure a boolean remains true while checking for collision

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl-2

i am trying to let my character land on a platform in my own SDL2 based framework. currently it is not working due to, if i have more than one platform, which is default if i spawn one. the character will only stay on the last platform added. the rest it will slowly fall through while the `grounded` boolean switches from `true` to `false`.

here is my code:

```
void NHTVScene::EntitiesGrounded()
{
    std::vector<Entity*>::iterator it = platformVector.begin();
    while (it != platformVector.end()) {
        if (player->isColliding((*it))) {
        player->velocity = Vector2(0, 0);
        player->grounded = true;
    }
    else if (!player->isColliding((*it))) {
        player->grounded = false;
    }

    it++;
    }
}
```

this function is called every deltatime update.

i know that this code makes it so that with every platform that is not colliding that the boolean is getting set to true, but i think its weird that it doesn't do that on the newest entry, and i have no clue how to do this properly.

I hope this is enough information to give some insight to my problem. if not, please let me know and i'll supply more.

Comment: You'd probably want to `break` out of the loop once you discover the character is in fact grounded.

Comment: that worked. thanks alot. i have been struggeling with this for waay to long. one of those things where i have been staring at it for to long

Answer (score 0):

1. It is easier to differentiate the `while` and `if else` clause with the proper indentation, please consider formatting the nested indentation levels a bit clearer.
2. I am making an assumption that `isColliding(Entity)` is a boolean and therefore checking false after already checking true should not necessary. Consider simplifying this logic.
3. If you want to establish the player as grounded after detecting a collision then that should be your exit criteria.

Something like this should do what you're looking for.

```
void NHTVScene::EntitiesGrounded()
{
    std::vector<Entity*>::iterator it = platformVector.begin();
    while (it != platformVector.end())
    {
        if (player->isColliding((*it)))
        {
            player->velocity = Vector2(0, 0);
            player->grounded = true;
            break; // exit criteria met
        }
        else
        {
            player->grounded = false;
        }
        it++;
    }
}
```